# oracle sql one is to many join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have four tables that I wanted to join to get the count of emp that has the same dir and type as follows:

**directory**

```
first_char   dir
-------------------
0000         Dir0
1111         Dir1
2222         Dir2
```

**emp_type**

```
type
------
typeA
typeB
typeC
```

**assigned_num**

```
no      emp_id
-------------------------
1111A   1
1111B   2
0000A   3
1111C   4
2222A   5
2222B   6
0000B   7
```

**emp**

```
id      type
--------------------
1       typeA
2       typeB
3       typeA
4       typeA
5       typeA    
6       typeB
7       typeA
```

**Expected output**

```
dir    type    # of emp
------------------------
Dir0   typeA   2          --> emp_id 3 and 7    
Dir0   typeB   0
Dir0   typeC   0
Dir1   typeA   2          --> emp_id 1 and 4
Dir1   typeB   1          --> emp_id 2
Dir1   typeC   0
Dir2   typeA   1          --> emp_id 5
Dir2   typeB   1          --> emp_id 6
Dir2   typeC   0
```

**I tried:**

```
SELECT dire.dir, etype.type, COUNT(anum.emp_id)
FROM emp_type etype
JOIN emp empl
ON etype.type = empl.type 
JOIN assigned_num anum 
ON empl.id = anum.emp_id
JOIN directory dire
ON anum.no LIKE dire.first_char  || '%'
GROUP BY dire.dir, etype.type;
```

but it wont display dir and type that has 0 emp count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: CAn you tell me last character of column `no` in Table `Assigned_num` represents what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your peoblem:

```
SELECT dir.dir, et.type,COUNT(emp.id) No_Of_Emp
FROM emp_Type et
CROSS JOIN Directory dir
LEFT JOIN assigned_num an
ON an.no LIKE dir.first_char  || '%' 
LEFT JOIN emp
ON et.type = emp.type
AND an.emp_id = emp.id
GROUP BY dir.dir, et.type
ORDER BY dir.dir, et.type
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
DIR      TYPE   NO_OF_EMP
=========================
Dir0    typeA    2
Dir0    typeB    0
Dir0    typeC    0
Dir1    typeA    2
Dir1    typeB    1
Dir1    typeC    0
Dir2    typeA    1
Dir2    typeB    1
Dir2    typeC    0
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2dd9/59